# Fancybox: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using the fancybox jquery plugin on my site but receiving an uncaught type error. Link: http://www.thestartupprogram.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my own question. Turned out changing the "$" to "jQuery" did the trick.